# Problem with xubuntu after boot from hard disk

Tags: boot, xubuntu, hard-drive

I'm now on Windows but I have Xubuntu too.

When I restart my computer and boot into Xubuntu, the loading screen appears and when is time to show up the desktop, nothing happens, it remains on black screen.

Before an hour or two everything was fine except downloading from Internet. When I try to download something an error appears and says that I don't have enough places to download. When I go to the File system and check how many place do I have on my hard disk it says, 36 GB on local disk (second partition).

When I restarted my computer the problem with the **black screen**

Comment: Could you post a filesystem layout describing all your partitions.

Comment: I have only 2 partitions, one C:\\ with windows,programs and xubuntu on it And E:\\ for my files, games, photos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On boot press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, On Grub menu → Advanced → Recovery mode
2. Run *Check all file systems*
3. Run *Try to make free space*
4. *Drop to root shell* Check for `/` free space by running `df`. If you still don't have enough free space (0.5GB may let you boot). Try deleting some non needed user files in `/home/user/`
5. Then: `exit`
6. Continue boot to normal mode: Choose *Resume*

Comment: thnx works,i on xubuntu now.. =)

Comment: My bad, works fine :)